# CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync crashes on Android Phone after taking and Saving Picture. It works well on Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, crash, android-emulator, android-camera

When I debug my solution in the android emulator, I can successfully take a picture with the CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync and it doesn't crash after taking the picture and tapping on the "good or accept" symbol to proceed.

But on my physical android device [Techno Spark 4 Air (Android 9)], after taking the picture, after I tap the "good or accept" symbol to proceed, the app appears to delay for some seconds and afterwards crashes.

No errors are displayed. I even put a DisplayAlert command just after the TakePhotoAsync, but it doesn't get there. I have put everything in a try...catch routine, but the apparent issue is not being trapped.

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,                           
                    Directory = "AAPictures",
                    Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.mp4"

                });

                if (file == null)
                    return;
```

Comment: This package was deprecated two years ago.  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#update-novemeber-2020

Comment: I am using the 6.0.1 Beta version of the plugin. It came out a month or two back. Any attempt to reference an earlier version will result in mono.linker issues.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the package belongs to the third-party. I am not sure if it has some issues and I recommend you use the [Xamarin.Essentials : Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android). This package belongs to the MicroSoft, and you can refer to the document.

Comment: I changed to Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker and everything appeared to be working well on the Android Emulator. When I archived the Release apk and deployed it to my phone, it started and freezed. After a couple of minutes, it complained that the app has stopped working. Is there a permission I have not set? At least, the app was working on the phone up to the point where I try to take a photo with the former plugin.

Comment: Are there any error information or signals on your phone? You can link your phone to your compiler instead using the Android Emulator. Then use the debug mode to run the project. You will see some issue information on the compiler.

Comment: Great. Let me do just that: linking my phone to my Development PC. Thanks.

Comment: This is the error message I am getting when I use my phone in place of the Android Emulator: Can't write in External Storage. This error message shows up maybe after I try it several times. But, in the Android Manifest File, the External Read & Write Storage flags are enabled. I even manually enabled the Location Feature in Camera App and it worked once, but since then it keeps crashing after I take a picture and tap to save it.

Comment: You can try to add the code `<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">` to your AndroidManifest.xml file.